# How is "for" used in "Having such a famous man for a father..." ?

Tags: past-participles, formal-language, for

> Having such a famous man for a father must have had an effect on Jason's childhood.

In this sentence I can't understand how **for** is used. I haven't read such a sentence before so I find it difficult to understand. I think 'as' in place of 'for' makes more sense.

Anyone please explain where I'm wrong because it's given on a English grammar check website.

Answer (score 2):

Either of these two definitions of ***for*** at [oxforddictionaries.com](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/for) might help...

> **4** Having (the thing mentioned) as a purpose or function.
>    *‘networks for the exchange of information’*
>    *‘the necessary tools for making a picture frame’*

...where *the relevant role/function* of the aforementioned famous man is *to be a father*. Alternatively, it may make more sense to some see it in terms of...

> **7** Representing (the thing mentioned)
>    *‘the ‘F’ is for Fascinating’*

...where we (the celebrity-obsessed public) see a very famous man (that we don't even *know* personally, but what the addressee sees is *his father* (the real man, not the public facade).

---

Note that it wouldn't make any difference if the sentence were changed to...

> *Having such a famous man **as** a father must have had an effect on Jason's childhood.*

But note also that whereas it's perfectly idiomatic to say...

> ***As*** a father, I don't think 15-year-olds should be drinking in bars

...it's most definitely *not* idiomatic to replace ***as*** with ***for*** in that context.